# solve tic tac toe with multi class classification

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying a multi-class classification approach to solve tic tac toe problem.
I am using regression classifier to solve a single step of tic tac toe. For simplicity, computer or classifier will always be the 2nd player. I am training the classifier with a data set like this. This is expected output and corresponding feature vector for each move to be made.

```
y - X
2 - 0 0 0 | 0 X 0 | 0 0 0    # pay for 'O' at 2th location
1 - 0 0 O | 0 X 0 | 0 X 0    # pay for 'O' at 1st location
...
```

I have distributed each of the feature 'O' or 'X' into binary 3 bit encoding.

```
0 => 0 0 1
O => 0 1 0
X => 1 0 0
```

I am trying with 100 row dataset and it is giving me 72% accuracy! But doesn't seem to improve with more data.
Or should I be representing the feature vector differently ?

**Edit:** Clarification of y values in the above examples.
1st example. State of board: 1st move made by human.

```
0 0 0
0 X 0
0 0 0
```

Now 2 ==> 2nd index of 1D array. It would be a good move to make.
Similarly, the next example, 1 means => 1st position in 1D representation of the board.

Comment: This is interesting! Can you clarify why y=2 in your first expected output and why y=1 in your second?

Comment: Solving a game with supervised learning is kind of a paradoxon. Solving typically means perfect-play and obtaining perfect-play needs a lot of data (and nonlinear ml-tools for most games; ignoring nonlinear preprocessings). You would need to generate many examples and every trained regressor will be worse than a simple-lookup table (no memory problems with TTT). Also: the sample-generation and learning is not connected in any way. This design can't do much (hardly spoken) without much (high-quality) data . Typically one would approach this with Reinforcement-learning like Q-learning.

Comment: @sascha Thanks for the knowledge. I knew my present approach is not really promising. What about Neural network ? Instead of going to specialized algorithms, why not try to mimic the model of our brain's way of learning to play a game ?

Comment: Yes, I expect that if your transform your output representation from 0-9 to a one-hot-encoding, you might get better result.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that if your transform your output representation from 0-8 to a **one-hot-encoding**, you might get better result. That's to say, you will have 9 output nodes, each corresponds to one position on board. Instead of saying y = 2, you say:

```
y = [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

At classification or evaluation time, choose the node that has the highest value as the predicted move.

Another suggestion is that since this state-space is small, you want to **exhaust** all possible states and generate the target labels for `y` for each of them. This is to provide more training examples (as mentioned by @sascha).

The third suggestion is: you might want to use 9 **logistic** nodes independently as the output, since this is actually a **multi-label** problem. That is, in certain cases, multiple locations are equally good.

The last suggestion is: the board is **symmetrical**, thus you could use this property to reduce the state space.

Comment: one-hot-encoding is a good suggestion. I have used this for number recognition myself. Hm, exhaustive data - this is most important, isn't it ! Looks like, this sort of classification is not the right way to go about solving this even though it is a good exercise to get some insights.

Comment: Right as @sascha pointed out, q-learning is the more principled way to go.